# Is $3 \ge 1$ or is it just $3 > 1$?

Tags: inequality, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Well, probably this might seem a really simple question (and it might be so too!), but off late me and my friends have been debating quite hard over this question.

> **Is $3 \ge 1$ or is it just $3 > 1$?**

Actually it all started here: if functions $f$ and $g$ satisfy $f>g$ then do they also satisfy $f \ge g$? All of us agreed. (are we wrong here itself?). After all, the $\ge$ symbol is basically 'greater than' **OR** 'equal too'. So if a function $f$ takes values greater than $g$, then definitely it satisfies the $\ge$ relation.

But then somehow the above mentioned question came up. My friends say that $3 \ge 1$ is absolutely wrong. Their reasoning: "under no circumstances can 3 be equal to 1", so $3 \ge 1$ is wrong.

My argument: $3 \ge 1$ is a mathematical statement which can either be true or false. It states that 3 is either greater than **OR** equal to 1. One of the conditions is satisfied and the two conditions are linked by an 'OR'. So $3\ge 1$ is true.

Who's right?

(please edit or add tags as i don't know what to tag the question as!)

Comment: You are right. As you point out, if one or both of $A$ and $B$ is true, then the sentence "$A$ or $B$" is true.

Comment: Tell him that $1\geq 1$. That will be fun.

Comment: Yup! Sure!!! Actually he is reading right now. Getting the opponent whipped after a long debate is fun :D

Comment: @ParthThakkar Don't think about it as an opponent! It is good to have such debates, specially when one has a rather informal understanding of a topic.

Comment: Ok. Will keep that in mind. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: $3\ge 1$ because it is not true that $1\gt 3$

Comment: @MarkBennet That is good to remark. $\neg(a>b)$ is $a\leq b$.

Comment: If it is not true that $3\geq 1$, what does $\geq$ mean? What would be the point?

Comment: That's the whole thing I was trying to explain to those guys, but then what they said was: "under no circumstances can 3 (a constant) be equal to 1, so how can we say $3\ge 1$?".

Comment: My algebra lecturer said "5 is a number or a banana", and "yesterday I went to the cinema or the theatre". I found the latter one particularly amusing, since he'd just explained that when a mathematician says "A or B" they mean "A or B or both".

Comment: You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right.

Regarding your friend's concern: The statement 'I am a person or I am a horse' is true. I am always a person, so this is true. It does not matter that it is impossible for me to be a horse.

Similarly, '3 is greater than or equal to 1' is always true. It is always true that 3 is greater than 1. It is never equal to 1, but this does not matter.

This question, like many others, can be resolved by returning to the definitions. For a statement of the form 'A or B' to obtain, at least one of A or B must be true. This is necessary and sufficient. As long as one of A or B is true, the status of the other doesn't matter. It doesn't even matter if the other can never be true. *All that matters is that at least one of them is true.*

For a more formal approach, consult any textbook on logic.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why they don't like this answer?

Answer (score 19):

You are correct, and so is your reasoning: $3\ge 1$ is precisely equivalent to the compound statement

$$3>1\quad\text{or}\quad3=1\;.$$

You might try pointing out to your friends that in order to be consistent, they would have to argue that ‘$4$ is even or odd’ is false, because $4$ is never odd!

Answer (score 6):

The statement "two is even or pigs fly" is *true*, as is anything of the form "[true] or [false]".

So yes, given two numbers $a,b$, exactly one of the following is true:

$$a<b$$
$$a=b$$
$$a>b$$

But it doesn't hurt anything to combine the true one with a false one, using "or".

Comment: Good point. Few can argue that for _any_ number $x$, $x>1$ or $x=1$ or $x<1$. Just because we know which one is true when $x$ is 3, doesn't mean the statement has become false.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. If $x$ is greater or equal to $y$, this means that there exists a non-negative number $a$ such that:
$$y + a = x$$
this of course true for $ 3 \text{ and } 1$ $(a=2)$, so indeed $3 \ge 1$.

Comment: This doesn't address the substance of the question, which is the definition of 'Or.'

Comment: I think it does address the question. We turn to a definition of greater than or equal and note that if a=0 the definition is still satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

In programming, if one writes

```
if (condition1 || condition2)
```

where || means OR and condition1 is true, condition2 is, in most languages if not all, not even evaluated - for the very same reason: it does no longer matter. The whole expression is true.

Comment: In programming, pigs might fly and I wouldnt care. This site is about math.

Comment: Agreed! The answer I meant to give was that the statement "A ≥ B" is read "A is greater than OR equal to B" and given that one condition is satisfied in a logical OR, the whole expression is true (regardless of the area of application). I'll refrain from obscure references and be more precise in the future, thanks for bashing on me!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. It's true that $3\geq 1$, however, if one wish to obtain the stronger statement, one can always specify that $3>1$. Both are correct, but the latter is more preferable.